# AgGrid Custom Floating filter - agSetColumnFilter not setting filter model with setModel()

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have implemented custom dropdown filter and treating it as floatingFilter. (I have enterprise version).

```
export class MultiSelectFilterComponent implements IFloatingFilterAngularComp, OnDestroy {}
```

I have method called applyFilter which does some logical calculation and at the end it sets model in ag-grid filter like below

```
const filter = this.params.api.getFilterInstance(this.colId);
const filterModel = this.filterData.filter(dropdownData => dropdownData.selected).map(value => value.value);
const filterObjectValue = filterModel.length > 0 ? filterModel : [this.noneFilter.value];
filter.setModel({
  values: filterObjectValue
});

this.params.api.onFilterChanged();
```

Here is question :

When I get `filterObjectValue : [1,2,3,4,5]` it does not get set in appliedModel. But when I convert this to Array of strings like this `filterObjectValue : ["1","2","3","4","5"]` this gets set in appliedModel.

How I get to know about appliedModel? When I print `filter` variable, I get know in appliedModelValues there.

I am debugging this weird bug like hell but not getting any solution. I read ag-grid library code and there was some condition where I found below code line

```
existingFormattedKeys_1.get(formattedKey)
```

Here whoever written this line trying to fetch formattedKey (which is integer) from existingFormattedKeys_1 map (which is map of keys in string). Obviously it will return nothing and flag is undefined. Due to this, Filter is not getting set in model and code flow is breaking.

Anyone have idea about this?